# Is this an example of a AlertDialog or PopupWindow in Android?

Tags: android, dialog

http://img139.imageshack.us/img139/1203/devicei.png

I've seen this in a few apps, and i have expiremented with both PopupWindow, and AlertDialog and I was confused which this was.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an `AlertDialog`. You can browse that app's source code [here](http://github.com/sunlightlabs/congress) (look at `com.sunlightlabs.android.congress.MainMenu`).

Comment: Just a note - the app's source code URL has moved to https://github.com/sunlightlabs/congress-android (the URL in the answer above now points to our API code, which serves the app).